# Scrapy shell view(response) not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-shell

When I open the Scrapy shell through the command `scrapy shell "http://quotes.toscrape.com/"` (this example comes from the Scrapy tutorial), I enter the command `view(response)` which opens my navigator (Firefox to be precise) with a path looking like `file:///tmp/tmpnzkkilst.html` and the error "File not found".

Any idea on how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a `scrapy` but the `firefox` issue. I experienced the same. Files existed in my `/tmp` folder, however `firefox` was unable to open them. In my case the `firefox` was installed from `snap` by default and for some reason it could not open the files in `/tmp`.

Resolved it by downloading and installing the `firefox` directly from Mozilla's website and replacing the `snap` one.